# How to replace CURSOR when it has effect on functions in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sql-server-2014

Please consider this code:

```
Declare @MyMinMaxTable Table
(
    [Min]    int,
    [Max]    int,
    [Desc]   NVARCHAR(50)
)

Insert into @MyMinMaxTable
values (0,12,N'Child'),
       (13,19,N'Teenager'),
       (20,25,N'Youth'),
       (25,40,N'Middle-aged'),
       (40,99,N'Old')

Declare @MyTable Table
(
    Id         int identity(1,1),
    [Year]     int,
    Age        int,
    MyCol2     int,
    MyCol3     int null
)

Insert into @MyTable
([Year], Age, MyCol2, MyCol3)
values 
(2012, 10, 1 , 1),
(2012, 28, 2 , 3),
(2012, 14, 1 , 7),
(2012, 24, 3 , 3),
(2012, 80, 1 , 6),
(2012, 39, 1 , 3),
(2012, 45, 1 , 5),
(2012, 23, 2 , 6),
(2012, 72, 3 , 8),
(2012, 17, 1 , null),
(2012, 62, 4 , 9),
(2012, 20, 1 , null),
(2012, 5, 1 , 9),
(2012, 8, 1 , 9),
(2012, 25, 1 , null),
(2012, 41, 2 , 2),
(2012, 26, 1 , 2),
(2012, 33, 4 , 2),
(2012, 40, 1 , 2),
(2012, 33, 2 , 3),
(2012, 41, 1 , 5),
(2012, 53, 1 , null),
(2012, 37, 1 , 3)

Declare @Result Table
(
    C0         NVARCHAR(50),
    c1         decimal(5,2),
    C2         decimal(5,2),
    C3         decimal(5,2)
)
```

The CURSOR part:

```
DECLARE @Min    int;
DECLARE @Max    int;
DECLARE @Desc   nvarchar(50);

DECLARE mycur CURSOR  
FOR
    SELECT [min],
           [max],
           [Desc]
    FROM   @MyMinMaxTable
OPEN mycur

FETCH NEXT FROM mycur INTO @Min, @Max, @Desc

WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Result
        SELECT @Desc As c0,
               (Cast(COUNT(CASE when Age >= @Min AND Age <= @Max  THEN 1 END) as decimal(5,2)) / cast(COUNT(Id) as decimal(5,2))) As c1,
               (Cast(COUNT(CASE when MyCol2 = 1 AND MyCol3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as decimal(5,2))  / cast(COUNT(CASE when Age >= @Min AND Age <= @Max  THEN 1 END) as decimal(5,2))) As c2,
               (Cast(COUNT(CASE when Age >= @Min AND Age <= @Max  ANd MyCol2 = 1 THEN 1 END) as decimal(5,2)) / cast(COUNT(CASE when MyCol2 = 1 THEN 1 END) as decimal(5,2))) As c3
        FROM   @MyTable AS td

    FETCH NEXT FROM mycur INTO @Min, @Max, @Desc
END 

CLOSE mycur
DEALLOCATE mycur

SELECT * FROM @Result
```

The problem is I want to remove `CURSOR` and write a query without it. How it can possible in this scenario?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  I for one do not want to make sense of cursor code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my question. Thanks for your attention

Comment: Can you please put sensible, descriptive column names in here? C1 and C2 don't tell the readers anything, and it's difficult to see the concept here. It appears that you want to classify persons within age brackets, but these table definitions have no concrete connection to a concept. Column names such as 'min' and 'max' are also not helpful. Also, why is C3 nullable, and is that even relevant to the concept?

Comment: @PittsburghDBA thanks for your attention. C1 , C2 , ...are in result table and the name of them doesn't matters. I think my question is so simle. I have table that I want to classify an do some calculatio in each class

Comment: **Negative votes do not matter to me. I don't know why some peoples just LOVE down voting. I spend 200 reputation. negative votes do not matter**

Comment: It is very difficult to determine the logic of the business rule while looking at MyCol1, MyCol2, and MyCol3 in CASE blocks. Those columns do have meaning, because they are driving CASE logic. Is it age? Is it number of classes attended? Are they flags? What is the BUSINESS goal? There are likely many efficient answers here, but the logic is so obfuscated as to make this hardly worth working on.

Comment: **I proud to all this down votes. Justice will never be lost.** @PittsburghDBA You are right in case of `MyCol1` and I change it. But how many important that `MyCol3` is what. It just check for null in a case statements and based on this I do some calculations.

Comment: @Arian, I thought you may have some mistakes in your calculations, but it seems cause is in your sample data. You have intersecting ages for periods `Youth - Middle-aged` and `Middle-aged - Old`. Because of that you are getting wrong results in your calculations. You should listen more to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. I unwound your query and rewrote it.
This one continues to work if you add additional ranges, and does not require CROSS APPLY, hard-coded subquery ranges or anything else.

Sorting is an exercise for you :-)

```
Declare @MyMinMaxTable Table
(
    [Min]    int,
    [Max]    int,
    [Desc]   NVARCHAR(50)
)

Insert into @MyMinMaxTable
values (0,12,N'Child'),
       (13,19,N'Teenager'),
       (20,25,N'Youth'),
       (25,40,N'Middle-aged'),
       (40,99,N'Old')

Declare @MyTable Table
(
    Id         int identity(1,1),
    [Year]     int,
    MyCol1     int,
    MyCol2     int,
    MyCol3     int null
)

Insert into @MyTable
([Year], MyCol1, MyCol2, MyCol3)
values 
(2012, 10, 1 , 1),
(2012, 28, 2 , 3),
(2012, 14, 1 , 7),
(2012, 24, 3 , 3),
(2012, 80, 1 , 6),
(2012, 39, 1 , 3),
(2012, 45, 1 , 5),
(2012, 23, 2 , 6),
(2012, 72, 3 , 8),
(2012, 17, 1 , null),
(2012, 62, 4 , 9),
(2012, 20, 1 , null),
(2012, 5, 1 , 9),
(2012, 8, 1 , 9),
(2012, 25, 1 , null),
(2012, 41, 2 , 2),
(2012, 26, 1 , 2),
(2012, 33, 4 , 2),
(2012, 40, 1 , 2),
(2012, 33, 2 , 3),
(2012, 41, 1 , 5),
(2012, 53, 1 , null),
(2012, 37, 1 , 3)

SELECT
    MMT.[Desc]
    --Ratio of (Age Bracket Matches) / (ALL Rows)
    , CAST(COUNT(1) / (SELECT CAST(COUNT(1) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS TotalRows FROM @MyTable) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS C1
    --Ratio of (Rows WHERE MyCol2 = 1 and MyCol3 = NULL) / (Age Bracket Matches)
    , CAST((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @MyTable WHERE MyCol2 = 1 AND MyCol3 IS NOT NULL) / CAST(COUNT(1) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS C2
    --Ratio of (Age Bracket Matches WHERE MyCol2 = 1) / (Rows WHERE WHERE MyCol2 = 1)
    , CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN T.MyCol2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / (SELECT CAST(COUNT(1) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) FROM @MyTable WHERE MyCol2 = 1) AS DECIMAL(15,2)) AS C3
FROM
    @MyMinMaxTable AS MMT
    INNER JOIN @MyTable AS T ON
        T.MyCol1 BETWEEN MMT.[Min] AND MMT.[Max]
GROUP BY
    MMT.[Desc]
```

Comment: That's great. You could also change the join to LEFT and make some small modifications for cases where there are no members of the set within particular ranges of age.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty! Make sure to change the start of Middle-aged to 26, and the start of Old to 41, so that your ranges do not overlap. You may also want one from 100 and up in case any centenarians show up in the data set.

Answer (score 5):

Try maybe a `CROSS JOIN` and filtering in your where clause or conditional `CASE` statements.  It's still unclear what your end goal is so the aggregates below will have to be adjusted, but this may be a good start:

```
SELECT 
  mm.[Desc],
  (CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN MyCol1 >= mm.Min AND MyCol1 <= mm.Max THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) / CAST(COUNT(Id) AS DECIMAL(5,2))) AS C1,
  (CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN MyCol2 = 1 AND MyCol3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) / CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN MyCol1 >= mm.Min AND MyCol1 <= mm.Max THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(5,2))) AS C2,
  (CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN MyCol1 >= mm.Min AND MyCol1 <= mm.Max AND MyCol2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) / CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN MyCol2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DECIMAL(5,2))) AS C3
FROM MyTable td
  CROSS JOIN MyMinMaxTable mm
GROUP BY mm.[Desc]
```

Comment: @Arian my answer still stands, see updated query for the other 2 columns

Comment: Execution plan of CROSS JOIN not suitable for me

Comment: You asked for an alternative and were given one, execution plan is another thing since we have no clue what your database looks like and how its indexed.  That part is up to you. You can always take this example and tweak it but its not our responsibility to perform your work for you.

Comment: @Arian:Execution of cross join is a set based operation and it is far better than your row by row approach.

Comment: @TheGameiswar I want to replace `CURSOR` for better performance and better query structure

Comment: Above answer replaces your cursor ,doesn't it ? ,it is far better than row by row operation

Comment: The result is not same for my script and above query

Comment: That is an issue,but this plan is definitely better than yours

Comment: @TheGameiswar, the query in this answer does produce the same result as the cursor in the question. The difference is in the rounding, because the cursor code inserts into a `@Result` table with `decimal(5,2)` columns and the query in this answer doesn't convert the final result of the ratio to `decimal(5,2)` and result has more decimal places.

Comment: @DanD I agree. The goal is totally obfuscated for some reason. Logical column names would illustrate the objective. Also, comments in the source saying things like "--Average age of attendee" or something would be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to divide your data into groups. Try this query. But I'm not sure about third column, especially without sample data

```
INSERT INTO @outTable
select
    mt.[Desc], count(*) / count([Id]) over ()
    , COUNT(CASE when MyCol2 = '1' AND MyCol3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) / count(*)
from
    MyTable td
    join MyMinMaxTable mt on td.MyCol1 between mt.[min] and mt.[max]
where
    td.[YEAR] = @Year
    and td.[Status] = 1
group by mt.[Desc]
```

Comment: Your query has error because `Id` doesn't appear in `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Error can be removed by changing `count([Id]) over ()` to `count(*) over ()`. But can you explain what are you calculating in your columns C1, C2, C3?

Comment: I saw the update. But there's no explanation for those fields

Comment: Can you rewrite your query based on my update? I have problem to produce `c3`

Comment: What explanation you need for those fields? Mycol1 is for age and the rest of fields did not matters

Comment: Don't let others unravel your code. Add some explanation. What are you trying to calculate. There maybe mistakes. For example, it seems like for column `c1` you are trying to calculate some kind of ratio. But sum of all values is more than 1. Is it correct?

Comment: @uzi - this is the crux of the issue. It starts with an obfuscated definition of the goal, which is complicating matters greatly here.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach can be by using `CROSS APPLY`.

```
   SELECT MM.[Desc], 
       CAST(C1.C1Count AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) / CAST(Tot.TotCount AS decimal (15, 2))  AS C1, 
       CAST(C2.C2Count AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) / CAST(C1.C1Count AS decimal (15, 2))    AS C2, 
       CAST(C3.C3Count AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) / CAST(C4.C4Count AS decimal (15, 2))    AS C2 
   FROM   @MyMinMaxTable MM 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(MyCol1) AS C1Count 
                    FROM   @MyTable 
                    WHERE  ( MyCol1 BETWEEN MM.Min AND MM.Max )) C1 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) C2Count 
                    FROM   @MyTable 
                    WHERE  MyCol2 = 1 
                           AND MyCol3 IS NOT NULL)C2 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) C3Count 
                    FROM   @MyTable 
                    WHERE  MyCol1 >= mm.Min 
                           AND MyCol1 <= mm.Max 
                           AND MyCol2 = 1)C3 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) C4Count 
                    FROM   @MyTable 
                    WHERE  MyCol2 = 1)C4 
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) TotCount 
                    FROM   @MyTable)Tot
```

Following is the output for the above query.

```
Desc                        C1                      C2                  C2
----------          --------------------    ---------------------   ---------------------
Child               0.130434782608695652    3.666666666666666666    0.200000000000000000
Teenager            0.086956521739130434    5.500000000000000000    0.133333333333333333
Youth               0.173913043478260869    2.750000000000000000    0.133333333333333333
Middle-aged         0.347826086956521739    1.375000000000000000    0.333333333333333333
Old                 0.347826086956521739    1.375000000000000000    0.333333333333333333
```

Comment: Thanks @PSK the result is same. The problem is with changing boundaries and add another grouping bound we should change that queries

Comment: I feel same is the case with any implementation , a new grouping will lead to change in any implementation until your are not forming your query dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation is ok to pre calculate "The count all records in @MyTable", “The count of records in @MyTable where MyCol2 = 1 and MyCol3 is not null” and “The count of records in @MyTable where MyCol2 = 1” and store them into variables.

It would make the script more readable and easier to understand.

Here it is. Hope this helps.

```
Declare @MyMinMaxTable Table
(
    [Min]    int,
    [Max]    int,
    [Desc]   NVARCHAR(50)
)

Insert into @MyMinMaxTable
values (0,12,N'Child'),
       (13,19,N'Teenager'),
       (20,25,N'Youth'),
       (25,40,N'Middle-aged'),
       (40,99,N'Old')

Declare @MyTable Table
(
    Id         int identity(1,1),
    [Year]     int,
    Age        int,
    MyCol2     int,
    MyCol3     int null
)

Insert into @MyTable
([Year], Age, MyCol2, MyCol3)
values 
(2012, 10, 1 , 1),
(2012, 28, 2 , 3),
(2012, 14, 1 , 7),
(2012, 24, 3 , 3),
(2012, 80, 1 , 6),
(2012, 39, 1 , 3),
(2012, 45, 1 , 5),
(2012, 23, 2 , 6),
(2012, 72, 3 , 8),
(2012, 17, 1 , null),
(2012, 62, 4 , 9),
(2012, 20, 1 , null),
(2012, 5, 1 , 9),
(2012, 8, 1 , 9),
(2012, 25, 1 , null),
(2012, 41, 2 , 2),
(2012, 26, 1 , 2),
(2012, 33, 4 , 2),
(2012, 40, 1 , 2),
(2012, 33, 2 , 3),
(2012, 41, 1 , 5),
(2012, 53, 1 , null),
(2012, 37, 1 , 3)

Declare @Result Table
(
    C0         NVARCHAR(50),
    c1         decimal(5,2),
    C2         decimal(5,2),
    C3         decimal(5,2)
)


-- ANSWER BEGIN HERE

-- The count all record in @MyTable
DECLARE @CountAll DECIMAL(5,2)
SET @CountAll = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @MyTable)

-- The count record in @MyTable where MyCol2 = 1 and MyCol3 is not null
DECLARE @CountMyCol2Eq1AndMyCol3NotNull DECIMAL(5,2)
SET @CountMyCol2Eq1AndMyCol3NotNull = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @MyTable WHERE MyCol2 = 1 AND MyCol3 IS NOT NULL)

-- The count record in @MyTable where MyCol2 = 1
DECLARE @CountMyCol2Eq1 DECIMAL(5,2)
SET @CountMyCol2Eq1 = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @MyTable WHERE MyCol2 = 1)

INSERT INTO @Result
SELECT mm.[Desc],
    COUNT(1) / @CountAll,
    @CountMyCol2Eq1AndMyCol3NotNull / COUNT(1),
    SUM(CASE WHEN tt.MyCol2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / @CountMyCol2Eq1
FROM @MyMinMAxTable mm
JOIN @MyTable tt
    ON mm.[Min] <= tt.Age
    AND mm.[Max] >= tt.Age
GROUP BY mm.[Desc]

SELECT * FROM @Result
```

Comment: Thanks your solution is same as @Pittsburgh DBA solution.

Comment: The query optimizer already calculates these subqueries as scalar values, so there is no reason to 'pre-calculate' them into variables. This approach complicates the situation without adding value. @Arian noticed this as a refactor of my query into something more complicated.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA yeah our solution looked very similar. Sorry I didn't see your answer before starting mine. I will thumb up your answer too.

Anyway, I understand that query optimizer already calculate the sub queries into scalar values. I just thought it would be more readable.

Comment: @JeremiahWidjaja Both approaches have merit, in certain ways. As you say, yours may be easier to read, especially for a newer developer, or someone with a procedural leaning. Mine can be used as a view. Life is full of options!